# Codeigniter-Style Mysql Does not yield any result on IE 8

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, internet-explorer-8

I'm running this query

```
$q = $this
        ->db
        ->select('R_ID,B_ID,NETWORK,Interface,Mask')
        ->where('R_ID', $rid)
        ->where('B_ID', $bid)          
        ->get('IpPlan');

return $q->result_array();
```

It returns a result in browsers like IE9, Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8.

I already tried

```
return $q->result();
```

but still no luck. Does anyone know the cause of this issue? Thanks.

Comment: probably something to do with your cache I suppose ....

Comment: It is impossible just print_r your result in controller before going to view. Check your variables there might some problem

Answer (score 1):

It's almost impossible, that a select (run in CodeIgniter DB layer) give different results depends on your browser. CSS or even HTML parsing can be different, but SQL is reliable from this point of view. So you should check your variable-chain:

- maybe your browser stores an old value of a variable (initialize them)
- clear browser caches
- restart browsers
- try another browsers

etc.

Comment: I've been trying different things to make it work and i found one thing. When i try to use just one WHERE clause, it works.

Comment: Ok. So My guess is that your problem will be not far from this $rid and $bid variables. Just for testing purpose, you should hardcode correct values to the query (instead of variables). I assume, it will work on every browser. After that, you can start to debug your variables through the whole code.

Comment: I got the root cause. I traced it back to the javascript. The JS seems not to work in IE8. I'll work on it to support such browser. Thanks.